# increment int within an inline if in python

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I have a value that starts as `None` but should become an `int` that gets incremented in a loop. I tried using an inline if to check if it is None and increment otherwise. However the inline if statement throws:

```
x = None
for _ in range(5):
    if x is None:
        x = 1
    else:
        x +=1
print(x)

x= None
for _ in range(5):
    x = 1 if x is None else +=1 #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    x +=1 if x is not None else 1 #TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'
print(x)
```

It works if you don't use the `+=` and operator and x explicitly: `x = 1 if x is None else x+1`. But I was wandering if or how it is possible to use `+=` in an inline if.

Comment: What you call "inline if" is a *conditional expression*. A `+=` statement is not an expression.

Comment: Why not start with `x = 0` then?

Comment: @UnholySheep the `x` is an attribute of an object from a third party module.

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert is does! But i also needed the information that it is not an actual "inline if".

Answer (score 0):

You are using the inline code properly with `x = 1 if x is None else x+1`, you can't use `+=` in inline.
To understand, let's add some parenthesis without affecting code:

```py
x = None
for _ in range(5):
    x = (1 if x is None else x+1)
    # same as
    if x is None:
        x = 1
    else:
        x = x + 1
```